# Trying to implement buttons to change Google Maps View

Tags: android, google-maps

So I am building an Android Application that basically just centers on my University and a few specific locations around the university.

I have a menu on the top left hand corner that has a bunch of buttons for my different views.

I want to make it so if I click normal view, the map will change to normal view, hybrid view = hybrid view etc.

I'm having trouble doing that and my aplication keep shutting down when it does so I've taken everything out of the onclick and am just wondering if anyone can help with the issue.

Thanks.

Here is the code below for my mainactivityclass.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

static final LatLng UC = new LatLng(-35.2366583, 149.0868123);
private static final float ZOOM_BY = -1.0f;
long duration = 5000;
float tilt = 0;
private static final int PAN_BY = 180;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng uc = new LatLng(-35.2366583, 149.0868123);
    LatLng uc_library = new LatLng(-35.2378895,149.0822935);
    LatLng uc_gym = new LatLng(-35.2384935,149.0855926);
    LatLng uc_mainparkingarea = new LatLng(-35.241702, 149.084667);
    LatLng uc_natsemcentre = new LatLng(-35.2405378,149.0858629);
    LatLng uc_studentcentre = new LatLng(-35.2389137,149.0825285);
    LatLng uc_hub = new LatLng(-35.2381962,149.0823544);

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(uc, 13));

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
            .target(uc)
            .zoom(13)
            .bearing(0)
            .build();

    // Animate the change in camera view over 2 seconds
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
            2000, null);


    //// Polylines are useful for marking paths and routes on the map.
    map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(-35.230900,149.0805000),
                    new LatLng(-35.234783, 149.091833),
                    new LatLng(-35.241979, 149.090240),
                    new LatLng(-35.243031, 149.073927),
                    new LatLng(-35.241152, 149.073545),
                    new LatLng(-35.230900,149.0805000))
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE).fillColor(Color.WHITE)
            );

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_library))
            .position(uc_library)
            .flat(true));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_gym))
            .position(uc_gym)
            .flat(true));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_parking))
            .position(uc_mainparkingarea)
            .flat(true));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_sc))
            .position(uc_natsemcentre)
            .flat(true));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_student_centre))
            .position(uc_studentcentre)
            .flat(true));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_the_hub))
            .position(uc_hub)
            .flat(true));
}

public void normalViewClick(MenuItem item) {

}

public void hybridViewClick(MenuItem item) {

}

public void satelliteViewClick(MenuItem item) {
}

public void terrainViewClick(MenuItem item) {
}

public void noneViewClick(MenuItem item) {

  }
}
```

LOGCAT DETAILS AS FOLLOWS

```
05-15 14:49:36.060 27708-27708/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 

(already on)
05-15 14:49:36.079 27708-27708/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-15 14:49:36.768 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
05-15 14:49:36.770 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-15 14:49:37.053 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
05-15 14:49:37.064 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/zygote: Unsupported class loader
05-15 14:49:37.065 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
05-15 14:49:37.067 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:220
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 220
05-15 14:49:37.086 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/zygote: Unsupported class loader
05-15 14:49:37.093 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
05-15 14:49:37.115 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12211000
05-15 14:49:37.123 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 12673026
05-15 14:49:37.239 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication E/zygote: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
05-15 14:49:37.386 27708-27713/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=22KB
05-15 14:49:37.387 27708-27713/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=22KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
05-15 14:49:37.484 27708-27738/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-15 14:49:37.611 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
05-15 14:49:37.732 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
05-15 14:49:37.733 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-15 14:49:37.733 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-15 14:49:37.733 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
05-15 14:49:37.733 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
05-15 14:49:37.744 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa2cec6e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
05-15 14:49:37.771 27708-27766/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2cec6e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xac44be10)
05-15 14:49:37.849 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
05-15 14:49:37.851 27708-27708/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ibrah.ucapplication, PID: 27708
    android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler normalViewClick in class com.example.ibrah.ucapplication.MainActivity
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:252)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:480)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:528)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:204)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:126)
        at com.example.ibrah.ucapplication.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3388)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:328)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:57)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: normalViewClick [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:248)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:480) 
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:528) 
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:204) 
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:126) 
        at com.example.ibrah.ucapplication.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:63) 
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3388) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:328) 
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332) 
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93) 
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455) 
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:57) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
05-15 14:49:39.526 27708-27763/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
05-15 14:49:39.532 27708-27763/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
05-15 14:49:39.535 27708-27763/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/zygote: Unsupported class loader
05-15 14:49:39.536 27708-27763/com.example.ibrah.ucapplication W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear. Can you edit for details?

Comment: please add the logcat errors while app is crushing.

Comment: Will do now. Ill change one of the button methods and send across

Comment: Where is your button OnClickListener?

Comment: My buttons are at the bottom of the code. Will edit and show screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but the problem is menuItem click.As you had not written menu click logic.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();


   switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
          return true;
      case R.id.//normalViewClick:
     normalViewClick(item);
      return true;
   //Like this for other    
}
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Make GoogleMap  object global to change the view programatically on MenuItem selection



 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.normal) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    } else if (id == R.id.hybrid) {

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    } else if (id == R.id.satellite) {

    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);


    } else if (id == R.id.Terrain) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```